# How to assign a value to textbox while dropdown changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list from dropdown.The dropdown select to get the value from db,after the string  value coudn't assigned to the Textbox.

**My controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCountryBasedCharge(Int64 ID)
        {
            OrderBilling objOrderBilling = new OrderBilling();
            OrderBilling objCalculate = new OrderBilling();
            objCalculate = objOrderBilling.AutoCompleteState(ID);
            string chargeid =Convert.ToString(objCalculate.ShippingCharge);
            return Content(chargeid);
        }
```

**My View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrytitles, 
 "-----------Select----------"
 , new { id = "txtBCountry", @class = "selectStyle" })</td><td><label style="color:red" >*</label>
   <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txtChargeAmts" />


<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var CountryID;
        $(function () {
            $("#txtBCountry").change(function () {
                CountryID = $("#txtBCountry option:selected").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '../Billing/GetCountryBasedCharge',
                    data: { ID: CountryID },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            alert(data);
       **$('#txtChargeAmts').html(data);**
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that your `data` parameter is getting a value, if that is the case your problem was that you tried to put the return value as html not as a value in the input text.

When you want to assign a value to form input tags you should use the `.val()` function

Read `.val()` [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Try to change this line:

```
$('#txtChargeAmts').html(data);
```

TO

```
$('#txtChargeAmts').val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#txtChargeAmts').val(data);
```

in place of

```
$('#txtChargeAmts').html(data);
```